# How can LanguageTextField achieve automatic prompts and syntax checking for external classes?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I extended LanguageTextField and wanted to input a piece of Java through it.
But it won't detect what my custom classes (such as the Utils and Request classes in the picture) should do. Let LanguageTextField also automatically prompt for my custom class

[image]

I am https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/16525354489234-How-can-LanguageTextField-achieve-automatic-prompts-and-syntax-checking-for-external-classes Initiated here, no one replied to me

Comment: Please [wait for the answer here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/16514351392658-How-can-LanguageTextField-achieve-automatic-prompts-and-syntax-checking-for-external-classes), our team is working on it.